# Why the complicated proof for existence of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

In proving the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators, the first step is to show that an eigenvalue exists (and then you do induction).

Over $\mathbb{C}$, this is easy, since it's an algebraicly closed field.

Over $\mathbb{R}$, the books I've seen use a sort've long proof. But if you have a self-adjoint real matrix, then it is also a self-adjoint complex matrix. Therefore you can find eigenvalues, and you know those eigenvalues will be real because it's self-adjoint. Done. What am I overlooking?

Comment: You might want to give some details about the long proof yu have in mind...

Comment: BTW, the spectral theorem for real self-adjoint matrices is actually *equivalent* to the existence of singular value decompositions, which in most proofs uses the  Weierstrass extreme value theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eigenvalues will be real but you still have to prove that they have real eigenvectors.

Comment: I can't see how is this related to the OP...perhaps you misread? Or perhaps I did, of course.

Comment: You're right. But suppose you have a complex eigenvector and the matrix and eigenvalue are real. Then the real (and imaginary) parts of the eigenvector will again be eigenvectors. Just weird that I've checked 2 books and they have super complicated proofs.

Comment: @user19192, you're right. And Lang does exactly that in his *Linear Algebra* (chapter XI in both 1st and 2d ed; the 3rd ed is different).